# Regular expression recursive replace (increasing indentation)

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I'm sure it should be possible and I'd like to avoid a function as it is a one off report on a page (Oracle 11g) but I'd really like to format the following string with line breaks with indentation for each subsequent replacement of " - " to show a hierarchy

As an example:

```
This is the base level - This is level 2 - And this is the second
```

So, I can do a start and replace the " - " with a line break and apply a CSS pre to ensure they're all on one line

But ideally, I'd like this:

```
This is the base level
> This is level 2
>> And this is the second
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that using Regular Expressions alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `listagg` if the padding is done within the first argument:

```
with rcte (id, value, lvl, result) as (
  select id, value, 1, regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from your_table
  union all
  select id, value, lvl + 1, regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
)
select id,
  listagg(case when lvl > 1 then rpad(chr(10), lvl, '>') || ' ' end || result)
    within group (order by lvl) as result
from rcte
group by id
order by id;
```

```
ID | RESULT
-: | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | This is the base level
     > This is level 2
     >> And this is the second           
 2 | Base only
```

But you also said:

> I can do a start and replace the " - " with a line break and apply a CSS pre to ensure they're all on one line

so if you want one line you can just not add the line break in the first place:

```
with rcte (id, value, lvl, result) as (
  select id, value, 1, regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from your_table
  union all
  select id, value, lvl + 1, regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
)
select id,
  listagg(case when lvl > 1 then rpad(' ', lvl, '>') || ' ' end || result)
    within group (order by lvl) as result
from rcte
group by id
order by id;
```

```
ID | RESULT
-: | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | This is the base level > This is level 2 >> And this is the second              
 2 | Base only
```

You could also add the > inside the recursive CTE, which might be neater:

```
with rcte (id, value, lvl, result) as (
  select id, value, 1, regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from your_table
  union all
  select id, value, lvl + 1,
    rpad('>', lvl, '>') || ' ' || regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where regexp_substr(value, '(.*?)( - |$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1) is not null
)
select id,
  listagg(result, ' ') within group (order by lvl) as result
from rcte
group by id
order by id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=05288e9cc07ba997a2579b817a3a1174)

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of *ugly*, but kind of *works* (at least, how I understood the question). See comments within code.

```
SQL> WITH test (col)
  2    -- Sample string
  3       AS (SELECT 'This is the base level - This is level 2 - And this is the second'
  4             FROM DUAL),
  5    -- Split it to rows (minus sign is a delimiter)
  6       temp
  7       AS (    SELECT LEVEL lvl,
  8                      TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (col,
  9                                           '[^-]+',
 10                                           1,
 11                                           LEVEL))
 12                         val
 13                 FROM test
 14           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (col, '-') + 1)
 15  -- join it back, using '>' along with CHR(10) as delimiter
 16  SELECT REPLACE (
 17            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, LPAD ('>', lvl - 1, '>') || val || CHR (10)) ORDER BY
 18                                                                                   lvl).EXTRACT (
 19               '//text()'),
 20            '&gt;',
 21            '>')
 22            result
 23    FROM temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is the base level
>This is level 2
>>And this is the second


SQL>
```

---

If you ask "why `XMLAGG` and not `LISTAGG`", it is because

```
 16  SELECT LISTAGG (val, LPAD ('>', lvl - 1, '>')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl)
 17    FROM temp;
SELECT LISTAGG (val, LPAD ('>', lvl - 1, '>')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl)
                                *
ERROR at line 16:
ORA-30496: Argument should be a constant.
```